# Generate JPA Entities with Annotations using XML

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I am trying to find a way to generate JPA Entities with some javax.validation Annotations using XML. Basically I modify an XML file and with some magic it'll generate the JPA java classes with the javax.validation Annotations within it. I can't seem to find the right combination of words to find this information online, so I came here. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What kind of XML file? A custom of yours or a *standard* one?

Comment: You could have a look at the [Maven Hibernate3 Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/index.html) and its several [goals](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: Any kind of format would be fine in my opinion it doesn't need to be in XML. Any format would work. My goal is to have it where I can modify 1 XML file and it modifies the Java code AND Database code.

Comment: Sos. the Hibernate3 Plugin seems to have what I'm looking for. Now just to play with it. Thank You.

Comment: Would you be interested in a tool that converts a database directly into JPA entities? I developed one using the Maven Hibernate3 Plugin, but I'm not starting from XML files as you asked, so I'm not sure this will be what you're looking for.